# getting a particular class value from a list of class on ther same element

Tags: jquery, regex

just ran into this problem ....

```
<div class="ipsum dolor_spec sit amet price1">Hello World!</div>
<div class="ipsum dolor_spec sit amet price2">Hello World!</div>
<div class="ipsum dolor_spec sit amet price3">Hello World!</div>
```

the code i have till now is

```
$("div[class*='price']").each(function(){
    var class_name= $(this).attr("class")    
});
```

prints "ipsum dolor_spec sit amet price1"

where as i just want price1, price2, price3 to be returned ?

i have tried ...

```
var classList =$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
    if (item === 'price*') {
       //do something
    }
});
```

the above is  from another stackoverflow answer my problem is the regex part how would i get it to match only "price*"

any help is appreciated ....

thanks

solved it b doing this ...

```
var classList =$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
                            $.each( classList, function(index, item){
                                if (item.match(/^price_qty([0-9]+)$/)) {
                                    console.log(item);
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: In your 1st example even if you get only price1,price2,price3 finally `class_name` have price3 only because you did not store it in a array.

Comment: @ManirajSS that is not the case you get the entire class list associated with the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is one of the ways to achieve this:

```
$("div[class*='price']").each(function(){
    var class_name= $(this).attr("class").split(" "),len = class_name.length, i = 0;    
    for(;i < len; i++){        
        if(class_name[i].indexOf("price") === 0){
            console.log(class_name[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/gnLd3h1u/2)

Comment: @NMFSDF welcome :) there are many ways to do this.. I mentioned one of those

Answer (score 0):

use **[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)**. A classList is to accessing an element's list of classes

```
$("div[class*='price']").each(function(i,elem){
   console.log(elem.classList[elem.classList.length-1])  // get all classes into array  and print the last class using  elem.classList.length-1
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xbb9raf0/)**

Comment: @Hiral , Ya i explained something .now see the my post